# Integrating Python analysis into Java Rest API

Tags: java, python, rest, analysis

My Java backend needs an analysis during an insert statement into a database, which I have to do with Python. Now the question arises how to connect a Java backend with a Python script. Should the Python script be created as a Restful API and then executed during the insert statement via an HTTP request or is this Bad Practice? Or are there alternative approaches I could look at?

Comment: If the python script is to be executed on the same box as the java service, I would say that designing an HTTP api just for this one call is a bit overkill.  From java you can call a shell command that can run the python script, that might be the easiest thing to do here.

Comment: Alright thanks alot